# How do you replace visual studio template variables in razor cshtml pages?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, templates, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a custom visual studio 2010 mvc3 project that we use in our shop for new projects. When replacing namespaces with the actual project name, everything works great until I get to my .cshtml pages. Is there a way to force the template engine to pass the variables in to the page?

I have something like the following:

```
<title>@$safeprojectname$.Constants.applicationName</title>
```

Is there a way I can set this up such that someone starting a new project doesn't have to replace any text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go into your project template's vstemplate file and make sure that every `ProjectItem` entry that uses parameters has the `ReplaceParameters="true"` attribute set.

Comment: So, do I have to edit the zip file that is created and add this in? Is there a way to access the vstemplate file elsewhere? I still haven't gotten it to work.

Comment: @IronicMuffin I don't know how you are creating your project template, but if you are using the Visual Studio SDK then you should be able to just edit the vstemplate file. Then once you zip it up and install it you might have to run `devenv.exe /InstallVsTemplates` to rebuild the project template cache in VS.

Comment: Haven't been using the SDk...I've just been setting up the template in a new project, then doing File -> Export Template. Is the SDK a better route?

Comment: @IronicMuffin The SDK gives you more control, specifically allowing you to edit the vstemplate file. The Export Template wizard just generates one for you and then you'd have to unzip the output, edit it manually, and rezip.

Comment: Ok, I guess that's what I have to do then. Thanks for the help.